# How to write a trigger in PostgreSQL to compare a field to a field in another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

This is the first time I'm trying out a trigger. I've understood the concept and use behind triggers, however I'm not too sure how to go about writing the procedure.

Basically I've got a table, which we'll call 'Money', which has a field called 'Max_transaction_amount', and another field called 'Currency_ID'  Then, I've got a table called 'Transactions'. Basically, what I want to achieve is a mechanism whereby whenever a new transaction is added to the 'Transactions' table, a check is carried out to see that the 'Count' of all the transactions pertaining to a certain currency does not exceed the 'Max_transaction_amount' in the table called 'Money', with respect to the 'Currency_ID'.

It seems like a very simple problem for users experienced with databases, however I'm still learning and would like to write such a procedure to get started off on the right foot.

Unfortunately I can't provide any code because I haven't the slightest clue as to how I'm going to do this. However, this is what I 'think' might work:

- The trigger would need to execute on update of the 'Transactions' table
- The procedure checks the 'Max_transaction_amount' in the record which is being added, by checking its 'Currency_ID'.
- A select statement is executed to find the amount of rows which conform to that specific 'Currency_ID'
- The 'Max_transaction_amount' field in the 'Money' table will be checked to see what the max amount is for that particular currency
- In the 'Transactions' table, the Count of all the records pertaining to that particular currency is compared to the 'max_transaction_amount'
- If it is less than or equal to the max amount, then the changes are saved.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

---

I've tried writing the following procedure... while the syntax is accepted, nothing happens if I try to exceed the amount. Could anyone kindly guide me in the right direction?

```
BEGIN

IF ((SELECT COUNT(Currency_ID) FROM "Transactions" WHERE "Currency_ID" = NEW.Currency_ID) > (SELECT "max_transaction_amount" FROM "Money" WHERE "Currency_ID" = NEW.Currency_ID)) THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error';

END IF;
END;
```

Comment: please show us the tables' DDL, sample data and two possible `Transactions` operations:  one that you expect to allow and one that you expect to reject.  (I think you say "UPDATE" when you mean "INSERT", "COUNT" when you mean "SUM", etc. -- examples would be clearer.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I do not have any sample data, as all this is still in the planning stages. Basically, what I want to accomplish is to see if the amount of records entered which have a specific ID, so hence the "COUNT" of such records, is less than or equal to the value specified in a field which is found in another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the way the max_transaction_amount is stored, but to me it sounds like you can achieve this with a balance column in the moneys table and a check constraint. The balance would then be updated each time a row is inserted into the transactions table

```
CREATE TABLE money 
(
   currency_id              integer not null,
   max_transaction_amount   numeric(18,2) not null,
   current_balance          numeric(18,2) not null default 0,
   primary key (currency_id),
   check (current_balance <= max_transaction_amount)
);

CREATE TABLE transactions 
(
  transaction_id       integer not null,
  transaction_amount   numeric(18,2) not null,
  currency_id          integer not null,
  primary key (transaction_id),
  foreign key (currency_id) references money (currency_id)
);
```

Now you only need to make sure that the current_balance is updated each time a transaction is inserted. This seems to be one of the rare occasions where a rule makes sense (but could be done in a trigger just as well - especially if you need to do more checks):

```
CREATE RULE transactions_insert AS 
  ON INSERT TO transactions
    DO UPDATE money 
          SET current_balance = current_balance + new.transaction_amount
       WHERE currency_id = new.currency_id;
```

Now when updating the `current_balance` column, the check constraint will make sure that the `max_transaction_amount` is not exceeded.

If you need to cover `UPDATE`s to the table, you need to create another rule:

```
CREATE RULE transactions_update AS 
  ON UPDATE TO transactions
    DO UPDATE money 
          SET current_balance = current_balance - old.transaction_amount + new.transaction_amount
       WHERE currency_id = new.currency_id;
```

Of course the two rules could be done with a single trigger function as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not too sure about this rule format, does it differ from a trigger procedure?

Comment: Rules and triggers are two completely different things. See the manual for details.